# Create a dedicated Database per user in a MEAN App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io, database-connection

I am working on a project that requires a dedicated database per registered user. I prefer working with MongoDB so I'm using that for the same *(Am I Right?)*. The app uses a **REST API** as the backend (written in **Node Express**) and an *AngularJS App*. So, what I think of doing is whenever a user makes a request to some API endpoint say, a GET request to `api/user/mydata`, I would create a connection to his particular database, fetch the required data, close the connection and return the fetched data as the response. *Is this approach correct?* Also, I'm using **Mongoose** as the ODM and *PassportJS* for user Authentication. Moreover, users of my app are mutually exclusive. There is no data connection between a user with any other registered user.

Comment: Why do you need a separate database? Your purpose can be solved by having multiple collections in 1 database.

Comment: No, I need a separate database per user. I'm actually creating a Stock Managment App. And, my users are my clients. Each database would have data like stocks sold, stocks available, order placed, customer billing details or the likes, related to stocks of a particular user in a particular database. I hope you understood my point.

Comment: Those things can be handled within 1 database also.

Comment: You can refer to this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1058/132123

Comment: Yeah, I read it all and concluded that I should go with the separate database only. But I'm confused between the two approaches. Should I go with connecting/disconnecting to the database upon each API endpoint request as mentioned in my question or, going with something like socket.io would be a better Idea. Or, you have a better idea on how to implement it? :)

Comment: Socket.io won't be able to get data from the database. You need to connect to database in order to get data right? How will socket.io help in that?

Comment: No, actually, Socket.io will create a socket connection per user to the app backend and upon socket creation, we would just connect to the database specific to that user and would close the connection to the database only when that socket closes i.e. when the user logs out! This is just an idea. I don't really know if it's possible to implement it.

Comment: It is possible. But in your question, you mention GET request. What is your question?

Comment: My question is which solution is better. The one with Socket.io? If yes, I would have to run mongoose.connect(databaseURL + '/' + USER_DB); per socket connection where USER_DB is the name of the database of a particular user. Let's say I have 1000 users then I would have 1000 sockets which means a thousand instances of mongoose.connect(). Is it allowed to have 1000 mongoose.connect instances in a single node app. If yes, is there a limit to it like 10 thousand or something?

Comment: Socket is required when you have to maintain a bi-directional connection. What is bi-directional in your case?

Comment: Also read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

Comment: @Utkarsh did you achieve your requirement if yes please post logic

Comment: @bipin Hi Bipin, I just posted my solution. Please do upvote the question and the answer it if you find it helpful. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Utkarsh did you use middleware for this and session and if you post some sample of code it will help me alot and thanks for your replay

Comment: @bipin I actually used Passport as an authentication middleware. You should try it. It's really good and the documentation is very good. You won't be needing my code. Let me know if you still do. And, thanks for upvoting my answer. Please upvote the question too. thanks :)

Comment: @Utkarsh, is  passport authentication only for social login or it can be used in normal login

Comment: @bipin It can be used in normal login as well. Check its docs and you would know for yourself. It's really good. Also, please upvote the question post. thank you. :)

Comment: @Utkarsh did you initialize you connection in passport middleware and i had upvoted your answer cmoomented below but it not very clear

Comment: @bipin Oh, I'm sorry. Actually, you would have to create a dedicated auth database for user authentication that would contain their auth creds and the name of the database they belong to. You would have to connect to this global database while you initialise passport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do that but only **without using Mongoose**. You would have to create a root connection to your MongoDB server (mind it, not to a particular database on that server) using the *mongodb* node module and then you can switch between the database as per your query requirement without creating a new connection per database as shown below:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// URL to the root of MongoDB Server and not a particular db
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Names
const dbName1 = 'myproject1';
const dbName2 = 'myproject2';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db1 = client.db(dbName1);
  const db2 = client.db(dbName2);

  client.close();
});
```

You can't do this through mongoose, as mongoose and its models require connection to be made to a particular database and not to just the root db server. Anyways, I didn't want to give up mongoose for my own project so I just had to resort to initializing the db connection and its models per HTTP request by the user and closing the connection upon response.